# Android firebase getValue() not working

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following JSON file

```
{
    "TestNode" : {
        "TestKey" : "TestValue",
        "TestKeyTwo" : "TestValueTwo"
    },
    "TestNode2" : {
        "One" : {
            "ItemOne" : "email@gmail.com",
            "ItemTwo" : "zYMnPqefn7BlGDidpOocff6Xcg==\nBKb1sfaDdgfe0=\n1yVcV0mciIQXtAf/4LqGdDw==\n",
            "ItemThree" : "name"
        },
        "Two" : {
            "email" : "emailtwo@gmail.com",
            "password" : "xFBvDPcnp/efebUhtefZ0+XMFfw==\ngAb5fSbzAefeQXc=\ng/WdCpusQl2umtPVOefefzjs1A==\n",
            "username" : "othername"
        }
    }
}
```

The listener code

```
TestNode.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(TestKey)) {
            String TestKeyString = TestNode.child(TestKey).getKey();
            String TestValueString = TestNode.child(TestKey).getValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

and I get the error

> Cant resolve method getValue();

P.S I haven't run the code yet, because of the above error

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information.  Post the code for the listener the returns the `DataSnapshot` for `TestNode`.  Also, this statement doesn't seem valid: `String TestKey = TestNode.child(TestKey).getKey();`.  How can you use `TestKey` before it has been initialized?  Also post the code the the exception you are getting with the stacktrace.

Comment: Ive updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 TestNode.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Log.d("TEST","key: "+dataSnapshot.getKey());
    Log.d("TEST","value: "+dataSnapshot.getValue());
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
 });
```

**Update**
Try this code to get only one child

```
 TestNode.orderByKey().equalTo(TestKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Log.d("TEST","key: "+dataSnapshot.getKey());
    Log.d("TEST","value: "+dataSnapshot.getValue());
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
 });
```

Comment: This would print out every child under TestNode, I only want one specific one

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code, this will work for sure:

```
TestNode.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(TestKey)) {


 String TestValueString = dataSnapshot.child(TestKey).getValue(String.class);

  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
 });
```

Hope this solves the problem. This  **will** give you the specific value of that key itself.